# Apache DirectorySlash 301 with custom, content negotiated response body

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, errordocument, content-negotiation

When Apache `mod_dir`'s `DirectorySlash` mechanism 301s a request that maps to a directory but that was missing its trailing slash, it produces a response body of type `text/html`, whatever the `Accept:` header of the request. While I understand that pretty much every client will just use the `Location:` header in the response to work out where to go, I'm wondering if it's possible to customise the response body to produce something other than `text/html`. In my specific case, I'm getting `application/rdf+xml` or `text/turtle` requests and returning like-encoded RDF responses. I'd like to be able to handle these missing-slash 301s with a response such as this:

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@base <http://www.example.com/>.

<resource> owl:sameAs <resource/>.
```

I've tried using rewrite rules and `ErrorDocument` in the `.htaccess` file like this:

```
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

# When no trailing slash, redirect to slashed path with a special ttl response body
ErrorDocument 301 /resource-see-other.ttl
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} text/turtle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resource$
RewriteRule .* /resource/ [L,R=301]

# When text/turtle request with trailing slash, return resource
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} text/turtle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resource/$
RewriteRule .* index.ttl [L]
```

This works OK. But it stops working as soon as I need to handle the cases for other content types. Although I can add another set of rewrite rules without any problems, I can't repeat the `ErrorDocument` directive in the `.htaccess` file; only the last such directive in the file will actually apply, resulting in all 301 responses getting the same response body.

I suppose if I wasn't restricted to `.htaccess` I might be able to use `<Location>` directives which would isolate the `ErrorDocument`s from each other.

So is there a way to do content negotiation on error response bodies?